# Justice Leaguer with a cowboy motif

Tags: dc, character-identification, dc-animated-universe

I saw this guy in the opening of an episode of Justice League: Unlimited. He was a muscular guy who wore a white cowboy hat, a red bandana over his face like a mask, a blue shirt and carried what looked like six-shooters. Fairly certain this *wasn't* Jonah Hex, as he looked to be from the modern era in spite of his attire, had a bulkier build and AFAICT, no facial deformities.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you are thinking of [Vigilante](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/Vigilante). He appears exactly as you describe.

[image: Picture of cowboy hero Vigilante wearing a white hat with a red bandana over his lower face and holding two revolvers]

Comment: Seems like that's what I find when I search randomly: https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=dcau+cowboy&ia=web but I might have a lucky search

Comment: He looks a whole lot like Superman in a different costume...

Comment: @RonJohn- there was a time I thought he was from some Elseworld's story where Clark somehow ended up back in time to the wild west.